# Sonar 5.2 Differential Dropdown widget error

Tags: widget, sonarqube

When I try to add Differential Dropdown widget to Main Dashboard in Sonar 5.2 I see following error in server log:

```
2016.01.08 09:27:28 ERROR web[rails] Can not render widget rules: undefined   method `strftime' for nil:NilClass
2016.01.08 09:27:28 ERROR web[rails]   compiled-template:20:in `_run_inline_1764444193_locals_dashboard_configuration_widget_widget_properties'
2016.01.08 09:27:28 ERROR web[rails]   org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
2016.01.08 09:27:28 ERROR web[rails]   /apps/eqbld/sonar/sonarqube-5.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
2016.01.08 09:27:28 ERROR web[rails]   /apps/eqbld/sonar/sonarqube-5.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
2016.01.08 09:27:28 ERROR web[rails]   /apps/eqbld/sonar/sonarqube-5.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
2016.01.08 09:27:28 ERROR web[rails]   /apps/eqbld/sonar/sonarqube-5.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:269:in `render'
2016.01.08 09:27:28 ERROR web[rails]   /apps/eqbld/sonar/sonarqube-5.2/web/WEB-INF/app/helpers/dashboard_helper.rb:168:in `widget_body'
2016.01.08 09:27:28 ERROR web[rails]   /apps/eqbld/sonar/sonarqube-5.2/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/_widget.html.erb:3:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47_widget46html46erb_locals_object_widget'
2016.01.08 09:27:28 ERROR web[rails]   org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Differential Dropdown widget is being removed as it doesn't support the latest versions of SonarQube, see [SONARWIDLB-13](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARWIDLB-13) . You should leverage built-in [Differential Views](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views) instead.